# Suma de valores de un mismo campo pero cambiando un valor según código

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sum

Buenas tardes querida comunidad, Necesito sumar los valores de una tabla que corresponden a un mismo campo, pero uno de esos valores debe quedar en negativo ya que dichos valores se dividen según código único.

Los códigos para valor positivo y negativo del mismo campo son los siguientes:

Positivo = 111201 Negativo = 120976

QRY

```
select cod_mvto,val_ml_mvto, 
case when cod_mvto = 120976 then val_ml_mvto * -1 
else val_ml_mvto * 1 end valor_movimiento 
from newafp.acr_saldos_movimientos 
where cod_mvto in (111201,120976)
```

Resultado

```
COD_MVTO    VALOR_MOVIMIENTO

120976  -83

111201  2907

111201  2563

120976  -66
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que dentro del sum el valor que tiene código 120976 lo reconozca como valor negativo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te adjunto mi resultado, simplemente multiplique por -1 el resultado de la suma, espero te ayude.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (COD_MVTO INT, VALOR_MOVIMIENTO INT)

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(120976, 83 )
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(111201, 2907)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(111201, 2563)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(120976, 66 )


SELECT COD_MVTO, 
    CASE WHEN COD_MVTO = 120976 THEN SUM(VALOR_MOVIMIENTO) * -1 ELSE SUM(VALOR_MOVIMIENTO) END AS suma
FROM #temp
GROUP BY COD_MVTO


DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, te comento lo que hice ya que al final me la pude idear jajaja.

sum(val_ml_mvto * case when cod_mvto = 120976 then
-1 else 1 end)

Answer (score 0):

Hay otra forma de llegar a la solución, lo comparto aunque se que ya obtuviste un resultado favorable a lo que necesitabas, pero siempre puede ser de ayuda.

En este caso te basas en que hay un código que te permite anticipar si el valor que se guarda en el campo se debe tratar como positivo o negativo y para eso puedes usar en ORACLE un decode.

```all
select sum(decode(cod_mvto, 120976, -val_ml_mvto, val_ml_mvto))
from newafp.acr_saldos_movimientos 
where cod_mvto in (111201,120976);
```

Espero sirva de algo.

Comment: Súper, gracias de todas formas, lo probaré a ver si me resulta mejor a lo que yo hice